Баг в коде для вычисления exp в C++
Я написал код для вычисления функции exp, но код работает не корректно. Результат работы программы ровно в половину меньше, как это исправить?
#include <iostream>

int factorial(int number);
float exp();

void main() {
    std::cout << exp() << std::endl;
}

float exp() {
    int x;
    float result = 1.0;
    std::cout << "Enter x: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i) {
        result += std::pow(x, i) / factorial(i);
    }
    return result;
}

int factorial(int number) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}


Умножить результат на два.

Если всегда в 2 раза меньше - просто умножайте на два :) Исправлять код для вычисления такого простого ряда, в котором используется pow и факториал - увольте, его надо писать нормально заново... Тем более что он у вас вообще вычисляет не пойми что: например, что это за суммирование с ограничением i<=x?...

@Harry ограничение суммирование, ведь EXP можно посчитать по формуле 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + ... x^n/n!

Но почему надо при этом останавливаться на члене не больше x? Если x=0.5, то сколько членов ряда у вас просуммируется?

@Harry x имеет тип данных int

Видимо ва напутали с формулой. Для ее работы нужно две переменных: значение, для которого вычисляется экспонента (по идее это должно обозначаться как x) и количество итераций по вычислению ряда (вообще их должно быть бесконечное количество, но тут их надо ограничить либо числом, либо по погрешности). А тут у вас x - это и значение и количество итераций.

Ну хорошо, x=1. Что получится? Да, а экспонента теперь вычисляется только для целых чисел? exp(1.5) больше не существует? Кстати, еще - это уже к проектированию - функция должна заниматься чем-то одним, а не одновременно и запрашивать значение, и считать...

@Harry ответом будет 2

@user7860670 можете немного расписать про ошибку в формуле?

Ошибка не в формуле, а в вашем коде. for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i) - не верно. Я уже как бы расписал... И exp 2 будет 7.389...

"ответом будет 2" А должно быть? https://microexcel.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/eksponenta-2.png

@Harry и должна быть 2, если подставить единицу в формулу и сложить, то получим 2, погрешность возникает из-за малого количества итераций

Слов нет, одни выражения...

Ладно, чтоб было понятно, как:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double Exp(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = 1, term = 1;
    for(int n = 1; abs(term) >= eps; ++n)
        sum += term *= x/n;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    cout << "Input x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "exp(" << x << ") = " << Exp(x,1e-7) << endl;
}

